# CDF of $X^+ = \max\{X,0\}$, (unsure about a specific step)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> If $F$ is the distribution function of $X$, find the distribution function of $X^+ = \max\{X,0\}$.

For $t < 0:$ 
$$
\mathbb{P}[X^+ \leq t] = 0
$$
For $t \geq 0 :$
$$
\mathbb{P}[X^+ \leq t]=
\mathbb{P}[X^+ \leq t|X \geq 0]\mathbb{P}[X \geq 0]+
\mathbb{P}[X^+ \leq t|X < 0]\mathbb{P}[X < 0]
$$

**Is it correct to procced by using the following ?**

$$
\mathbb{P}[X^+ \leq t|X \geq 0] = \mathbb{P}[X \leq t] \tag1
$$
$$
\mathbb{P}[X^+ \leq t|X < 0] = \mathbb{P}[t \geq 0] = 1 \tag2
$$
If so,
$$
\mathbb{P}[X^+ \leq t]=
\mathbb{P}[X \leq t]\mathbb{P}[X \geq 0]
+\mathbb{P}[X < 0]
=F(t)[1-F(0^-)]+F(0^-)
$$
**Is the final answer correct?**

**If $(1)$ and $(2)$ are correct how can we prove them with the conditional probability definition?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making things way too complicated. For $t \geq 0$, $X^{+} \leq t$ iff $X \leq t$ so the answer is just $F(t)$ when $t \geq 0$.